# Fetch API - how to perform an action once data is retrieved, but before doing anything with the data?

Tags: javascript

The code below retrieves data from database.

Before the data is retrieved, a wait message is displayed. Once the data is retrieved, the message should be removed.

What would be the best place to execute the `remove_wait_message` function?

Currently it sits in `do_stuff_to_data`, but it does not seem logical, as those two functions are not in any way correlated.

```
           function main() {

                function get_data() {

                    let url = 'http://localhost:8000/query_database'
                    fetch(url)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json => do_stuff_to_data(json))
                }

                function do_stuff_to_data(json) {
                    remove_wait_message()
                    console.log(json)
                }

                function remove_wait_message() {
                    let wait_msg = document.getElementById('wait_message')
                    document.body.removeChild(wait_message)
                }

                get_data()

            }

            main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: @Edward: To be honest, I don't know what is wrong with my question then: the code is fully functional, I am only asking for help in refactoring it (moving function execution somewhere else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the line that's invoking the function call is the code that knows about the UI. So it's logical that it's done at the call site rather than elsewhere. For example:

```
// Define functionality in inert functions.
const getData = () => fetch(...).then(res => res.json())

const processData = () => { ... }

const showWaitMessage = () => { ... }

chost hideWaitMessage = () => { ... }

// When you actually want to do stuff, just call them.   
showWaitMessage()

getData() 
  .then(data => {
    hideWaitMessage()
    processData(data)
  })
```

In more structured frameworks like Angular, you'll have greater separation between UI code and logic code. You don't want to call UI functions in places that have no business with the UI at all.

```
// A class housing all the data fetching logic.
// In this code, you'll have no (official/non-hacky) way to reach the UI.
@Injectable({ ... })
class DataService {
  constructor(someHttpClient){
    this.someHttpClient = someHttpClient
  }
  getData(){
    return this.someHttpClient.fetch().then(r => r.json())
  }
}

// A class that handles the UI.
@Component({ ... })
class YourComponent {
  constructor(dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService
  }
  showWaitMessage() {
    ...
  }
  hideWaitMessage() {
    ...
  }
  processData() {
    ...
  }
  async doSomething(){
    this.showWaitMessage()
    const data = this.dataService.getData()
    this.hideWaitMessage()
    this.processData(data) 
  }
}
```

You can read more about this by researching on [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). In a gist, you write small independent functions. Then some "glue code" just calls into these functions to compose a larger functionality. In the example above, `doSomething()` glues together `showWaitMessage`, `getData`, `hideWaitMessage` and `processData` while all four functions are unaware of each other.